# PHP is it a bad practice to have a class and then use it in the same file?

Tags: php, class, oop

Is it a bad practice to have a `class` in a file and then at the end of that same `php` file to have a small chunk of code in which to use that class? For example:

```
<?php

class Class{
    //some code here
}

$class = new Class();
//do something with it
```

And if it is a bad practice, can somebody please explain me why?(i'm just at the beginning with classes :-s)

Thank you!

Comment: Every place you include the script will have the class already instantiated.

Comment: it is if you're going to be using this for multiple files.

Comment: Could also be useful to have a read about namespaces as well (http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php) as they are used for various things including autoloaders.

Comment: Thank you all for taking time to answer to my question! I understand it now! <3 :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally that is considered bad practice. It limits reusability of that class. It is best to have class definitions in their own file, then include that file anywhere that class is used. Files that contain class (or function) definitions should have no side effects.

For example you might have a file called `SomeClass.php` that looks like this

```
<?php

class SomeClass {
    // code here
}
```

Then in `index.php` you can include that file and use the class

```
<?php

include "SomeClass.php";

$class = new SomeClass('some data');
$class->someMethod();
```

The advantage of setting it up this way is if you later need to use the same class again you can just include that file again.

in `anotherfile.php`

```
<?php

include "SomeClass.php";

$differentInstance = new SomeClass('different data');
$differentInstance->someMethod();
```

[PHP Standards Recommendations (PSR)](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) is a community managed set of guidelines for PHP that I recommend you read through for more detailed information about questions like this. Specifically [PSR-1 Basic Coding Standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) and [PSR-2 Coding Style Guide](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).

Section 2.3 of PSR-1 explains more about this specifically.

Comment: Thank you @jfadich, i understand it now! :D